# Android Device back button functionality in Jquery mobile application

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-mobile

Could anyone suggest how to control the android mobile device's back button functionality in an HTML5 phonegap mobile application....?

For example:

An application which has multiple html files linked together...
like ---- index ----> page 1 ----> page 2 ---> etc...

when an user clicks the device's back button, the following page transitions should occur.

1. when the device's back button is clicked in Page 2, it should be directed to page 1.
2. when the device's back button is clicked in Page 1, it should be directed to index page
3. When the device's back button is clicked in the index page, the page should exit.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Android navigation guidelines](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html) recommend, navigation is essential part of the user experience, this is  the reason you need to agree with that guidelines to ensure user behavior in expected ways.

Answer (score 0):

The physical / fixed software back button of Android is part of OS. You can't override it from JQuery.